# Класс наследник ButtonBase

Tags: c#, wpf

привет сделал класс и наследовал от ButtonBase

```
MyClass = new MyClass
            {
                Height = 100,
                Content = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"B.jpg", UriKind.Relative)),
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                Width = 100,
                Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
                BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
                BorderThickness = new Thickness(2),
            };
            MyClass.Click += MyClass_Click;
            Field.Children.Add(MyClass);
```

Все вроде ок.Событие работает но почему то не нету заднего фона и границы

Comment: Шаблон покажете?

Comment: У `CheckBox` тоже нету рамки, например, а это кнопка...

Comment: Вы уверены, что вам необходимо реализовать свой класс? Возможно лучшим решением будет просто определить стили или добавить поведение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Background property applies only to the resting state of a control. The default style of the control specifies its appearance when the state of the control changes. For example, if you set the Background property on a Button, the button has that value only when it is not pressed or disabled. If you want to create a control that has a more advanced customization of the background, you must define the control's style.

Как говорит MSDN, это свойтсво можно определить для контрола в состоянии покоя. Если хотите свой фон для кнопки вообще-нужно переопределять через стиль.

Пример из MSDN. Фон меняется при нажатии на кнопку:

```
<Button FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold">Click the Background
<Button.Template>
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
  <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
     <ContentPresenter/>
  </Border>
 </ControlTemplate>
 </Button.Template>
 <Button.Style>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
     </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
</Button.Style>
</Button>
```